# Is there a recommendation for how to use pagination in cosmosdb with .NET SDK v3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pagination, azure-cosmosdb

I am currently implementing CosmosDB .NET SDK v3.
For pagination I am using OFFSET LIMIT SQL-API functionality.
This works well with small datasets. For Example

```
SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c._ts OFFSET 3 LIMIT 20
```

But following query with larger offset leads to immense performance issues (5 mins. execution time):

```
SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c._ts OFFSET 5000 LIMIT 500
```

Are there special options which need to be turned on in the database (index etc.) or are there any special request options in the SDK?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Does `OFFSET 5000 LIMIT 20` also take 5 minutes to execute?

Comment: Yes. The larger the offset the greater the execution time.

Comment: Can you verify that this behavior is also try without using a system field (like the `_ts`)? It is generally not recommended to order by date using `_ts`.

Comment: This behaviour also happens using fields other than _ts like own fields, e.g. "tenant". It also happens without using a ORDER BY which is btw. not necessary for  OFFSET, LIMIT in CosmosDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to be expected. You are executing a cross partition query across thousands of documents that don't live together. Cosmos is trying to give you the results you want but performing a cross partition query with ordering and pagination just isn't something that Cosmos DB is meant to be fast or efficient on in the first place.

Limiting this query into a single partition will actually improve performance significantly since Cosmos will know that all the data lives in a single physical partition. Cross partition queries as part of your regular application's workflow are a big no no and should not be used. You should only be looking up documents by id+partition key or querying using the partition key in the query or the partition header.

Comment: Thanks. Querying over all partitions in one container instead of all items in one container increases performance enormously.